# Error compiling qt creator / qt widget example

Tags: c++, linux, qt, g++

After installing QT 5.9 Creator on Ubuntu Linux I cannot compile and run examples that use QT Widgets. Here is the g++ call that is executed by QT Creator:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/matthias/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib -o gallery main.o qrc_gallery.o   -L/home/matthias/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

The error is:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL Makefile:245: recipe for target
>   'gallery' failed collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
>   [gallery] Error 1 20:16:53: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with
>   code 2. Error while building/deploying project gallery (kit: Desktop
>   Qt 5.9.1 GCC 64bit) When executing step "Make"

Obviously the parameter -lGL is causing the error. How do I fix that ?

Comment: Try to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` package

Comment: Try searching here or google, already answered and first hit in the search results...

Answer (score 0):

Install package libgl1-mesa-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```